# Is there any api or method that returns me the year of any technology launched or released?

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to find the year and month of particular technology say snapdragon 625 so I want to know the year and month in which it got launched or released.

I have tried Wikipedia api to get the details of the whole page of that particular title but it is not working properly. Please help.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, so we can help you.

Comment: I tried using the "wikipedia" library and fetch the content from it. Then searched the sentences having keyword say "snapdragon 435" and then extracting the year from it. But it is not necessary that a sentence with the keyword contains the year of launch for example - "Snapdragon 435 is a good processor. It is launched in 2016". So now I can't get the year by this sentence containing "snapdragon 435" as the keyword.

Comment: @philoez98 can you do something for this?